# Is there way to reset slider to image 1?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a slider that will work on hover but there is one thing I would like to add is reset. For example, if visitor hovers on the slideshow and he is on 4th image then when he hovers out and hover on it again then slide should start from image 1, not from image 4.
Please Help!

Here is the code.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
      $('.slides').cycle({
        fx: 'none',
        speed: 4000,
        timeout: 70,
      }).cycle("pause");

      $('.slideshow-block').hover(function() {
        $(this).find('.slides').addClass('active').cycle('resume');
      }, function() {
        $(this).find('.slides').removeClass('active').cycle('pause');
      });
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
}

.slideshow-block {
  position: relative;
  width: 1150px;
  height: 530px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: url('img/3-1.png');
}

.slides {
  z-index: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.slides.active {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <div class="slideshow-block">
    <ul class="slides">
      <li><img src="img/3-1.png" /></li>
      <li><img src="img/3-2.png" /></li>
      <li><img src="img/3-3.png" /></li>
      <li><img src="img/3-4.png" /></li>
      <li><img src="img/3-5.png" /></li>
      <li><img src="img/3-6.png" /></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: In JS add one more `});` at the end and include jQuery.

Comment: Thanks! But how can I add reset value every time a new hover comes in on slideshow.

Answer (score 1):

This may help you:

```
$('.slideshow-block').hover(function(){
     setTimeout(function () {
         $('.slides').cycle(0);
     }, 100);
     $(this).find('.slides').addClass('active').cycle('resume');

 }, function(){
     $(this).find('.slides').removeClass('active').cycle('pause');

 });
```